# Facebook API - Share. Comment not working

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-share

I implemented fb share functionality on my website. I used Open Graph action:

```
function shareOnFacebook() {
    FB.ui({
        method: 'share_open_graph',
        action_type: 'og.likes',
        action_properties: JSON.stringify({
            object: '<url>'
        })
    }, function(response) {});
}
```

The page to share contains meta-tags: `fb:app_id, og:type, og:url, og:title, og:image, og:description`
Sharing works, but text entered in personalized message box is not showing up on facebook page. I tested the page using Object Debugger and everything was fine. Could anybody help me with this?

One more question: the dialog doesn't close after sharing. Should I add some parameters or somehow close it by my own?

Thank you!

Comment: I have the same issue using the Javascript SDK, so it seems to be a cross-platform problem.